# How to create changeable width in fixed layout table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table containing three `<td>` cells.

- The width of the first `<td>` should depend on the content.
- the width of the second `<td>` should be fixed forever.
- the width of the third `<td>` should fill the remaining space.

**Note1:** My website is **responsive**; the width of third `<td>` should be changed in different screen.

**Note2:** For preventing going out the content of third `<td>`, I should use `table-layout: fixed;` and `width: 100%;` for my table. Also, I need to use `word-wrap: break-word;` for the `<td>`s. the point is that I don't want to use `word-break: break-all;` instead of `word-wrap`. *(because it breaks the words in the middle `<td>`)*

---

**Here is my attempt:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="VN">depends on the number of digit</td>
         <td class="S">always fixed</td>
         <td class="CT">all of the rest (remaining)</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
   width: 60%;
}

table{
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}

td{
   word-wrap: break-word;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.VN{
   width: auto;
}

.S{
   width: 10px;
}

.CT{
   width: 98%;
}
```

Also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ttpmomLd/) is a fiddle.

---

What I want is like these:

**example1:**

```
+-+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|4|fix|this is a test...!                                     |
+-+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

**example2:**

```
+----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|2   |fix|this is a test...!                                  |
+----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|    |fix|this has not any first <td>...!                     |
+----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
|1234|fix|this has not any first <td>...!                     |
+----+---+----------------------------------------------------+
```

**example3:**

```
+---+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
|123|fix|the width of number of vote up cell should be        |
|   |   |changeable and it should be noted that this cell is  |
|   |   |break-word.                                          |
+---+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

**example4:**

```
+---+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
|123|fix|It is a integrated testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt|
|   |   |ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt|
|   |   |tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt             |
+---+---+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

**example5:**

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|fix|this has not any first <td>.. then remove VN cell!       |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
|fix|this has not any first <td>.. then remove VN cell!       |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Do I need to use JavaScript for implementing what I need?

Comment: Use paragraph in a cell, and give width to it

Comment: @Elyor  your mean is `<p>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this property:

`white-space: pre-line;`

There's more values with different behavior [**here**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)