# how to detect certain number of consecutive characters and put a space after them

Tags: php, regex

I have a *textarea* and want before insert in the database check it for: detecting 20 integrated characters and put a space after twentieth character.

Here is an example:

```
$var = 'hello worlddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd!';
```

I want this output:

```
$newvar = 'hello worldddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddddddd ddddd!';
```

**Point:** So there is a point, I want to disable this severance for `href` content. For example:

```
$var = '<a href="www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm">link</a>';
```

Then I want a intact output *(because the long text is `href` value)*:

```
$newvar = '<a href="www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm">link</a>';
```

Is it possible ?

---

**Edit:** In fact I would like to avoid deterioration links and put space for all thing else. for example:

```
$var    = '<a href"www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm">link</a>';
$newvar = '<a href"www.google.c ommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm">link</ a>';
```

because missing `=` after `href`.

Comment: In your expected output you have a space after 16 d since you said you want space after 20 duplicate character

Comment: @Kasramvd no no, duplicate is not important, just 20 integrated characters.

Comment: As a hint you can replace the result of `(\w{19})(\w)` with `\1\2 `

Comment: @Kasramvd the most important point for me is detecting `href` value and leting it go ! anyway thanks, I will try it

Comment: @Sajad https://regex101.com/r/fG5nY8/2 <- Play around see what different things does and always read the explanation there.

Comment: `^((?!href).)*\w{19}(\w)`

Comment: I think this is not a regex task, seems simple at first look! but you can not do it with regex but without it you can first check for existence of `href` is string then add a space after each 20 consecutive character.

Comment: @Kasramvd yeah, I can implement it via php, but it takes `0.05 sec` time, It is much for me, the performance will drop. If I can do that via regex, I'm sure that will be very faster

Comment: This probably wont help (might even annoy you ;) ), but it can be done in .NET like `Regex.Replace("hello worlddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd!\r\n<a href=\"www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm\">link</a>", "(?<!href=\"[^\"]*)((?<ch>.)(\\k<ch>){19})", "$1 ");`. You need support for quantifiers in look-behinds, and php doesn't support that :( Edit: The regex part is `(?<!href=\"[^\"]*)((?<ch>.)(\\k<ch>){19})`.

Comment: @Kasramvd please check out the answer of my question.

Comment: @Sajad Unfortunately python's regex engine doesn't supports `\G`. using it would be a simple task.

Comment: @Kasramvd aha, alright ;-) do you use of phython for web or windows app ?

Comment: @Sajad And how you excluded the `href`?What about if your first string contains none word characters for example `helloworld#dddddddddddddddd@ddddd$dddddddddddddddddddddddddd`

Comment: If you want to accept none word characters (like what I attempted to do) your regex will match `'<a href="www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm">link</a>'`

Comment: Check this https://regex101.com/r/gK7xV3/6

Comment: @Kasramvd actually I did not get your point, but [here](https://regex101.com/r/gK7xV3/4) is my solution. and I tested, it is fine for your example

Comment: @Sajad You now `\w` will match any word character contain numbers ,alphabets,and underscore.and `\W` will match any none word character. so if you use `[\w\W]` to match strings like `helloworld#dddddddddddddddd@ddddd$dddddddddddddddddddddddddd` it will also match the string contain `href`

Comment: @Kasramvd look, I don't know ! can you *please* give me a fiddle ? *(with correct answer)*

Comment: If you want to exclude the `href` from it you need a negative look behind. check https://regex101.com/r/gK7xV3/7

Comment: @Kasramvd OW ! got it, really thanks

Comment: @Sajad You're welcome dude!

Comment: @Kasramvd are you removed one of your comment ?! [counterexample example for the answer]

Comment: @Sajad I don't know but I think I add a link to your comment about using regex but no it's gone! I thought I had a connection problem.

Comment: @Kasramvd I want to put thin space (`&thinsp;`) instead of space in my regex, is it possible ?

Comment: What do you _need_ this for? If this is about issues such as long random user input not distorting your web page layout, then you might be better of handling this using CSS in the first place, using properties such as `word-wrap` or `word-break`.

Comment: @CBroe in my website, css fails. please take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993684/how-to-create-changeable-width-in-fixed-layout-table)

Comment: Well that other question looks more like you choosing the wrong tool for the job to begin with … a flexbox layout might be best suited for what you want to achieve there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with regex:

```
((?<=\s)\w{19}|(?<=\G)\w{19})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gK7xV3/2)
and raplece with '$1 '

**EDIT**
Try with this:

```
(<a href="[^\n]+?<\/a>|[^\s]{19}|(?<=\G)[^\s]{19}(?=[^\n]+$))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gK7xV3/4)
however it will add space () after whole `<a href="...."</a>` part

Comment: please put `href="` instead of `any symbol`, is it possible ?

Comment: @Sajad what do you mean by `any symbol`? this regex will insert space before every 20th censecutive character (A-Za-z_0-9) if there will be space before that, so it will not match href=".... Or do you want to match it?

Comment: thanks, but the first one is better, no I don't want to match `href` value.  the problem of first one is still it will not be matched: `href"www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm"`. it should be matched, because it has not `=` after `href`.

Comment: I want to JUST the value of `href` remains intact ! `<a href="remines intact"></a>`

Comment: I would like to avoid deterioration links, and match all thing else.

Comment: @Sajad I updated answer, I don't have any other ideas

Comment: @Sajad but remebe about additional space ` ` character, and if <a href> will be nested (if it could be) there will be problem. I am happy it halped

Comment: Really sorry for asking again, So I need to one regex else to check out something is between this: `<a href="anything">` and `</a>`. In other word in first I want to use of your solution, and then  in second I need to check out the output once time again just for the name of link, can you *please* give me a regex ?

Comment: can you please replace `&thinsp;` instead of space in your code?

Comment: @Sajad in which place? you mean `(<a href="[^\n]+?<\/a>|[^&#8201]{19}|(?<=\G)[^&#8201]{19}(?=[^\n]+$))`?

Answer (score 1):

try this code , I test it and get correct result

```
$s = 'hello worlddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd! <a href="www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm">link</a>';
$array = explode(" ", $s);

$str="";
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    if (!preg_match("/href/", $value))
    {
//        $subArray=preg_split("/([.]{19})/", $value);
//        print_r($subArray);
        $str.=" ";
        $str.= preg_replace('/([^\s]{19})/', '$1 ', $value);
    }else{
         $str.=" ".$value;
    }

}
echo $str;
```

Comment: just copy and past in new php file to view result

Comment: I checked it, It has some problem, test this please: `< href="www.google.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm">link</a>`

Comment: So it is not a link, because `a` is removed, then should be matched

Comment: it is sensetive to href not `<a href`

Comment: you are right, but it is not useful for me, anyway +1 voteup for your try. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87011/discussion-between-mohammad-gholami-and-sajad).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use preg replace for this.

Example: $newvar = preg_replace('/([^\s]{20})/', '$1 ', $var);

This searches for 20 non space characters in a row and adds a space char after them.

Comment: your solution is fine, but that is a small problem, It adds a space even for `href` values. how can I prevent this ?

Comment: And it would match any sequence of more than 20 characters like `PNEUMONOULTRAMICROSCOPICSILICOVOLCANOCONIOSIS` ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can check regex matching with preg_match function that return true or false
see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and
try this:

```
if(preg_match('/([^\s]{19})/', $var)){
preg_replace('/([^\s]{19})/', '$1 ', $var);
}
```

Comment: where is detecting `href` value ?

Comment: look, I need to detect 6 previous characters of `$marched`, how can I do that ?